# Maven exec:java : how to open and read a file in the resources directory?

Tags: java, maven

here is the structure of my project.

```
proj
  ---src
    ----main
        ----java
            ----Main.java
        ----resources
             ----res.txt
```

I am using m2eclipse plugin with Eclipse. 
In Main.java, I have

```
File f = new File("res.txt");  System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

When I run mvn exec:java, the path got printed out is "...\proj\res.txt". How can I make it look for the resource file in "...\proj\target\classes" directory?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers to my original question. I have a follow-up questions:

So basically what I want to do is to have the Main class read the "res.txt" and then generate a new "newres.txt" to the resources directory so that I can package this new "newres.txt" to the jar file in the package phase later. Currently I mounted this exec:java to the prepare-package phase. How should I create this "newres.txt" in the resources directory without a hard-coded absolute path or depending on the directory structure of Maven?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess I will answer my own question, `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`
works the best for me, especially when the project produces a jar dependency for another web project.

Comment: You are the best! THANK YOU

Answer (score 16):

Figure I'd add to the answers.

You can also use:

```
InputStream file = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("res.txt");
```

Comment: This solved my problem for me! Thank you so much for taking the time to write this solution up!!!

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
InputStream IS = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("res.txt");
```

to access the content of `res.txt`. Pay attention to the encoding of your text file (beware of defaults). If your maven project is set on UTF-8 for example, make sure `res.txt` is encoded in UTF-8 too, otherwise, you'll get funny errors at runtime.

Comment: More on this in a blog post I created recently: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/07/maven-how-to-access-filesdata-in.html

Comment: See http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html?page=2  about when to use a leading '/' for the resource path.

Answer (score 1):

When run from eclipse, `res.txt` is created in/reader from the folder where eclipse is started.  Hence the output.

If you want to make the code look at the file in a specific folder, which is present in your classpath, then you should try using [getResourceAsStream()](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=33721) method.

Alternately you can specify the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is anther solution:

```
String str = "target/classes/res.txt";

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(str));
```

If you exec `java` in root folder, and you resource will compile to `target/classes` folder, you can write you code like this.