# How to create a file in src/main/resources

Tags: java, file, maven, file-io

If I do this

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "/sudoinput.txt");
```

Its trying to write to this location on the server. I am not sure if this is a writable
place.

```
FILE NAME (fos)::::::::::::::::::/opt/tomcat/temp/./sudoinput.txt
FILE NAME (fis)::::::::::::::::::/opt/tomcat/temp/./sudoinput.txt
```

I wanted to write to 
    webapps/sudoku/WEB-INF/classes
which is basically
    C:\Users...\git\sudo-project\sudo\src\main\resources

On Eclipse Windows 7 I get this
error
src\main\resources\sudoinput.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
if I give

```
fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/sudoinput.txt");
```

I have tried this too:

```
fis = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\sudoinput.txt");
```

but doesn't work.

how should I create a fileinputstream to be able to write to src/main/resources ?
please note that I am using eclipse windows to do dev and will be uploading the .war file on to a unix server if this changes the way in which the paths need to be specified.

Answer (score 5):

The `src/main/resources` folder is a folder that is supposed to contain **resources** for your application. As you noted, maven packages these files to the root of your file so that you can access them in your library.

Have a look at the [Maven documentation about the standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

In certain cases, it is possible to write to the context but it is not a good idea to try it. Depending on how your webapp is deployed, you might **not** be able to write into the directory. Consider the case when you deploy a .war archive. This would mean that you try to write into the war archive and this won't be possible.

A better idea would be to use a **temporary file**. In that way you can be sure this will work, regardless of the way your web application is deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Sandiip Patil. If you didn't have folder inside your resources then path will be `/sudoinput.txt` or in folder `/folder_name/sudoinput.txt.` For getting file from resources you should use `YourClass.class.getResource("/filename.txt");`

For example

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(TestStats.class.getResourceAsStream("/123.txt"));
```

or

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new `FileInputStream(TestStats.class.getResource("/123.txt").getPath()));`
```

Also look at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024353/maven-execjava-how-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-the-resources-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the file created under resources and call .class.getresource(your_file_name_or_path_separated_with_forward_slash);

See if it works for you.

Comment: i am not sure if i am following; how can i keep or create a file in src/main/resources? ; fis = new FileInputStream("/src/main/resources/sudoinput.txt"); isn't working. iam not creating this file from eclipse before hand to write to it. its something thats created from code

Answer (score 0):

If you like to create files in `webapps/sudoku/WEB-INF/classes` which is in the end within the created WAR file which can be achieved by putting the files you want into `src/main/resources/`
This means in other words you need to create the folder `src/main/resources` and put the files you like into this directory.