# Can you write to a file in src/main/resources?

Tags: java, maven, file-io, filewriter

Question is in the Title, Here's my code which dosen't seem to work:

```
    File counterValues = new File(getClass().getResource(COUNTER_VALUES_FILE).getFile());      
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(counterValues);

    out.write("TEST");

    out.close();
```

where `COUNTER_VALUES_FILE` is `private static final String COUNTER_VALUES_FILE = "/data/counter_values.csv";`

I have also tried:

```
    File counterValues = new File(getClass().getResource(COUNTER_VALUES_FILE).toURI());
```

It has made me believe it might not be possible, but i don't see why not if i can read from the file!

Comment: what is the error that you see ?

Comment: there is no error, or exception being thrown, its just not writing to the file in question

Comment: is it just a difference in read vs write permissions on the file / directory?

Comment: ill check now and post results

Comment: It might be writing in the classes directory. For example if you are using maven to build your project, see if it is getting generated in {PROJECT_DIR}/target/classes

Comment: You can have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554085/how-to-create-a-file-in-src-main-resources

Comment: It totally depends on the context of your app. If you run from the root directory of the project of course you can--but it may not be doing what you actually *think* it is, and you almost certainly should *not* write to the *source of your program* from within that program.