# Can i write file located at classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to write a text file at classpath. want to make some changes in that file.

this is spring boot application and packaging it as a jar. So basically this text file is located in jar & I want to make changes to that file.

Don't know it is possible or not.

but please suggest to me how I can do that?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: NullPointerException

Comment: Even if you could, you really shouldn't. Why do you need to change a file inside a jar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating resource files at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889793/updating-resource-files-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files inside a jar can be read from (called resource files in general).

You cannot modify them directly though. For that, you need them to be outside the jar.

Possible duplicate of [Updating resource files at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889793/updating-resource-files-at-runtime)

If it is a .properties file though, there are ways to do it. 

Following blog seems helpful (https://crunchify.com/java-properties-files-how-to-update-config-properties-file-in-java/)